# Как отключить сворачивание кода в Android studio?

Tags: android-studio

Не могу отключить сворачивание кода в студии. Нашел только хот-кей. Но каждый раз нажимать надоедает. Отключение "closures" не помогает.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

File -> Settings.. -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding

Галочки в секции *Collapse by Default* указывают, какие части кода сворачивать по умолчанию.

[image: scrn]